# WooCommerce not enqueuing its scripts

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to create a new theme in WordPress powered by WooCommerce. The problem is that WooCommerce for some reason doesn't enqueue its scripts, so the "Add to cart" Ajax feature and sorting drop down don't work at all. "Add to cart" works but it has to load the page.

I am specially stuck on the sorting option. I have tried to use another theme, "TopShop". After activating this theme, the sorting option works fine, but in my own custom theme it doesn't. When I inspect the code, there's no `woocommerce.min.js` file; I know that is the problem but how to fix it?

Comment: I just cleared out all my functions.php code and the problem still exists.

Answer (score 1):

Here was the problem.
I just didn't add the

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

in my footer.php file.

so simple but important.
I guess woocommerce group should check if wp_footer() doesn't exists add the scripts in header instead because I have wp_head() set up in my header.php